# Obter valor de escalões

Tags: microsoft-excel

Queria saber qual(ais) a(s) formula(s) para obter um valor de um escalão a partir de uma tabela pré-definida.

Por exemplo, considere que em uma planilha eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
| A   |  B   |
|-----|------|
| 245 | 4,5% |
| 256 | 6%   |
| 300 | 7%   |
```

Assim, ao digitar em uma outra célula um valor qualquer, por exemplo, `256`, eu gostaria de uma fórmula que automaticamente encontrasse o valor do escalão correspondente na tabela (nesse caso, `6%`).

Explicando melhor: ao colocar um valor entre 0 e 245 era devolvido 4,5 se colocasse um valor entre 246 e 256 era devolvido 6% e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: @bfavaretto, esta pergunta não deveria ter sido fechada como não clara? Fórmulas em Excel estão dentro do escopo do site (até porque já há muitas perguntas desse tipo por aqui). Não?

Comment: João, bem vindo ao SOPt. A sua pergunta não me parece nada clara. Esse "exemplo" que você posta, é o conteúdo de uma ou de mais células? É uma string de texto? Se sim, sua dificuldade é procurar um valor (uma sub-string) nela e achar o percentual correspondente? Por favor, edite a questão para fornecer mais detalhes. Isso ajudará que você tenha respostas mais rapidamente e certamente ajudará para que a sua pergunta não seja fechada/suspensa e/ou negativada. E se ainda não o fez, leia a [help], pois este site não é um fórum.

Comment: @João queria te ajudar, melhora a pergunta! obrigado.

Comment: @LuizVieira Pra mim devia ser off, mas ok... Eu reabro assim que ele esclarecer o que não está claro. João Filipe, a gente precisa entender qual é o critério da sua sequência de números na coluna B.

Comment: -1: A ideia dele  é a seguinte: até 245 devolve 4.5%; de 245 (exclusive) a 256 devolve 6%, etc. Só que o AP funciona por telepatia.

Comment: @bfavaretto Se quiser podemos abrir uma discussão no Meta a respeito de perguntas sobre fórmulas estarem ou não no escopo. Eu tenho a opinião de que estão porque não deixa de envolver programação e até alguns níveis de lógica.

Comment: João, obrigado por editar e tentar melhorar. Eu também editei a pergunta pra tentar melhorá-la ainda um pouco mais. Mas ainda assim há dúvidas. Na sua pergunta original vc menciona que deve ser `7%` para o valor `257`, mas esse valor não consta na sua tabela. Se você não explicar *exatamente* o que precisa e qual é a sua dificuldade, vai ficar mesmo muito difícil alguém conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo Ok, é o seu direito votar como -1. E o AP realmente está com dificuldade para explicar o que precisa. Mas, você não acha que é mais útil para a comunidade ajudar de forma construtiva? :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Eu já ajudei de forma construtiva: usei o meu conversor de ondas telepáticas para traduzir a questão. E ainda posso ajudar mais: procure a função PROCV (ou VLOOKUP em inglês). Além disso, pelo que percebi, os votos negativos devem ser dados quando as questões têm problemas. Eu empenhei-me, como faço quase sempre, em justificar o meu voto negativo para que o AP corrija a questão.

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo Eu creio que temos uma visão distinta sobre o que é uma forma construtiva. Mas, ok, sem problemas.

Comment: @LuizVieira O que sugeria então? Editar a questão da forma como eu imagino que o utilizador se quer exprimir? Se alguém não se dá sequer ao trabalho de ser o mais claro possível quando solicita a ajuda de outras pessoas, eu considero uma grande falta de educação e empenho. Mas isso, admito, pode ter a ver com diferenças culturais. Não sei se no Brasil toleram mais as coisas do que eu. Ainda por cima o autor da pergunta até está em Portugal, de acordo com o perfil dele.

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo Desculpe, não era a minha intenção criar uma discussão não relacionada aqui. Então, não vou continuar nessa interação, ok? Mas, já que você perguntou, eu sugeriria não usar ironia com um recém-chegado. Você tem toda razão a respeito dos erros na pergunta, só que eu acredito que seria mais útil auxiliá-lo para que melhore o conteúdo sem afastá-lo do site.

Comment: @LuizVieira Não precisa de discussão no meta, já que o fechamento foi uma decisão unilateral minha, e posso revertê-lo. Só não reabri ainda porque continua confusa a pergunta. Seria importante que o autor dela se manifestasse aqui nos comentários!

Comment: @bfavaretto Ok. Também acho que não deve ser reaberta ainda até que ele se manifeste. :)

Comment: Obrigado @LuizVieira por "endireitar" a pergunta... mas o objectivo é mesmo esse obter o valor da percentagem, explicando melhor, ao colocar um valor entre 0 e 245 era devolvido 4,5 se colocasse um valor entre 246 e 256 era devolvido 6% e assim sucessivamente

Comment: Ok, reabri a pergunta (CC @LuizVieira)

Comment: @bfavaretto na verdade eu não disse que deveria ser reaberto, mas sim fechado como "Não clara", no caso anteriormente foi fechada como "fora do escopo", concordo totalmente em fechar ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o colega Alexandre [já havia adiantado em um comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105277/obter-valor-de-escal%C3%B5es?noredirect=1#comment216268_105277), há uma função disponível no Excel chamada [`PROCV`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/PROCV-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-PROCV-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) (na versão em Português, ou `VLOOKUP` na versão em Inglês) que permite fazer buscas automatizadas em tabelas. A sintaxe para o uso dessa função é a seguinte:

```
=PROCV(Valor a ser Buscado;Range da tabela para busca;Índice numérico da coluna a ser devolvida)
```

> Observe que se a sua versão do Excel for em inglês você deve separar
>   os parâmetros com vírgula (`,`) no lugar de ponto-e-vírgula (`;`).

Para deixar a sua solução mais automatizada, eu sugiro nomear a sua tabela (por exemplo, usando o nome `Escalões`), e então utilizar esse nome no lugar do *range*. Para fazer isso, é só selecionar a tabela e dar um nome no campo disponível ao lado esquerdo das fórmulas, próximo ao *ribbon*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, você pode usar, por exemplo, a seguinte chamada para obter o valor desejado:

```
=PROCV(D4;Escalões;2)
```

Note que a função para na última linha com valor menor ou igual ao procurado, então funciona da forma como vc deseja (usando o mesmo escalão para intervalos). Só que você precisa ter ao menos uma linha com o valor padrão para valores menores do que `245` (se eles existirem), caso contrário a fórmula retorna erro (como ilustrado abaixo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nossa legal Luiz e @ AlexandreCartaxo - Mas uma duvida, por que 200 causou `#N/D`, o 200 não está no "range" de 0 á 245?

Comment: Eu expliquei na resposta. A função para na última linha de valor menor do que o procurado. Como ele não existe e *não há linha* anterior, dá erro. Se quiser, adicione uma linha com valor 0 só para ter esse retorno.

Comment: A entendi o range é de A:1 até `A:2 - 1` (me fiz entender? ou ficou confuso rs), agora fez sentido, muito bom +1

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta. Mas se eu colocar 246 vai dar 4,5% e o objectivo era dar 6

Comment: É muito simples de alterar para fazer funcionar: construa a sua tabela de forma que os valores sejam os iniciais dos intervalos, e não os finais. Por exemplo, ao invés de ter `245` (o último do intervalo anterior) com `4,5%`, defina o `246` (o primeiro do próximo intervalo) com `6%`.