# Fórmula - receber valores de um intervalo de células para outro, exceto células vazias

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho um intervalo de células contendo células vazias e outras não, dispostas em uma linha e preciso de uma formula que receba esses valores em uma coluna, exceto as células vazias, abaixo um exemplo do que preciso, acrescentando que os referidos intervalos são nomeados "BlanksRange" e "NoBlanksRange"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá. Você pode editar a pergunta para fornecer um exemplo visual do que quer fazer? Não está muito claro.

Comment: ok! vou simplificar.

Comment: @LuizVieira vi na tag e nao achei nenhuma outra pergunta a respeito de formula. Por isso comentei que poderia estar fora do escopo.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Tem algumas. Aliás, essa discussão sobre dentro ou fora do escopo é bem comum. A última vez que a tive foi nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105277/obter-valor-de-escal%C3%B5es

Comment: Por favor, use Markdown para formatar seus posts, HTML fica muito confuso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Você removeu da pergunta a indicação de que `BanksRange` era uma lista. Além disso, não ofereceu um exemplo com dados sobre o que quer fazer. Do jeito que a pergunta está, alguém tem que gastar tempo analisando a sua fórmula para tentar entender o problema (isso se a sua fórmula estiver correta). Se o seu problema é só mover os dados entre disposições horizontal x vertical, há a opção "transpor" na caixa de diálogo "colar especial". Por favor, seja mais claro no seu problema.

Comment: @Luiz Vieira Conforme sugeriu, inseri uma imagem como exemplo do que precisava; já havia tentado usar a opção "transpor", mas no meu caso não funcionou; analisei as formulas que postei como exemplo e acabei encontrado a solução. Peço desculpas pelos erros que cometi. Grato.

Comment: Sem problemas. Eu vi a alteração e votei para reabrir. Agora, se você mesmo achou a solução, não edite a pergunta para incluí-la no corpo da pergunta. Adicione uma resposta você mesmo (e explique como essa resposta funciona, para ajudar outros leitores no futuro!). No momento não é possível adicionar uma resposta porque a pergunta está suspensa. Mas se ela for reaberta, por favor, prossiga dessa forma ok?

Comment: Ok!, assim farei.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de postar minha pergunta, já havia efetuado pesquisas na web e encontrei esta [formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/NoBlanks.aspx) próxima do que precisava, porém os intervalos são de coluna para coluna e como explicado na pergunta, necessitava de linha para coluna, tentei adapta-la mas não estava obtendo êxito, razão pela qual solicitei auxílio neste sítio. Posteriormente passei a analisar a formula que havia baixado e descobri que bastava trocar de posição os termos da formula "ENDEREÇO(núm_lin;núm_col)", e deu certo.
Formula exemplo:

> ```
> {=SE(LIN()-LIN(NoBlanks)+1>LINS(BlanksRange)-CONTAR.VAZIO(Blanks);"";INDIRETO(ENDEREÇO(MENOR((SE(Blanks<>"";LIN(Blanks);LIN()+LINS(Blanks)));LIN()-LIN(NoBlanks)+1);COL(Blanks);4)))}
> ```

Formula modificada:

> ```
> {=SE(LIN()-LIN(NoBlanks)+1>COLS(Blanks)-CONTAR.VAZIO(Blanks);"";INDIRETO(ENDEREÇO(LIN(Blanks);MENOR((SE(Blanks<>"";COL(Blanks);COL()+COLS(Blanks)));LIN()-LIN(NoBlanks)+1);4)))}
> ```

Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]